# batch command that moves certain files within folder and sub folders all to a separate single folder

Tags: batch-file, command, revit

I have a batch command that will move certain files from one folder to another folder, as follows:

```
move /-y "U:\REVIT\REVIT FAMILES\*.00*.rfa" "U:\REVIT\Revit Backup Files"
pause
```

This moves the backup files that are created and have extensions of `.001.rfa`, `.002.rfa` etc. to another folder, but it only moves the files in that particular folder and does not move any from sub folders that exist as well. Could anyone please help with adding this function in?

Comment: Do you want to reflect the source directory hierarchy in the target directory, or do you want to move all files there in a flat manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preserving the Directory Hierarchy

In case you want to preserve the directory hierarchy, you can do the following:

```cmd
robocopy "U:\REVIT\REVIT FAMILES" "U:\REVIT\Revit Backup Files" "*.00*.rfa" /S /MOV /XC /XN /XO
```

The `/XC /XN /XO` options prevent from overwriting. Note that there is no prompt. Remove them to force overwriting already existing destination files.

---

Alternatively, you can use `xcopy` and `del`:

```cmd
xcopy /Y /S /I "U:\REVIT\REVIT FAMILES\*.00*.rfa" "U:\REVIT\Revit Backup Files"
del /S "U:\REVIT\REVIT FAMILES\*.00*.rfa"
```

The `/Y` option forces to overwrite already existing destination files. When you change it to `/-Y` to achieve a prompt, `del` does not care about the selections and still deletes all of the matching source files.

---

Finally, a third option was to use a `for` loop:

```cmd
set "TARGET=U:\REVIT\Revit Backup Files"
pushd "U:\REVIT\REVIT FAMILES"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%F in ('xcopy /L /S /Y /I "*.00*.rfa" "%TARGET%"') do (
    2> nul md "%TARGET%\%%F\.."
    move /-Y "%%F" "%TARGET%\%%F"
)
popd
```

The `xcopy /L` just lists the proposed files as paths relative to the source directory, but does not actually copy (due to `/L`). Every iterated file is moved by the `move` command; `/-Y` forces a prompt in case a destination file already exists. The `md` command is needed to create every sub-directory in the destination directory, `2> nul` suppresses the error message in case one already exists.

---

#### Not Preserving the Directory Hierarchy

Again a `for` loop is needed, but this time `dir /B /S` replaces `xcopy /L`:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "U:\REVIT\REVIT FAMILES\*.00*.rfa"') do (
    move /-Y "%%F" "U:\REVIT\Revit Backup Files\%%~nxF"
)
```

The `~nx` modifier extracts the pure file name (base name plus extension) from the path in `%%F`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I don't think there is any way I would have been able to add this in myself! I went for the last option of not preserving the directory hierarchy so that all files merge into one folder, although the other options will be useful if this does become necessary. If I just add 'Pause' to the end of this, does that mean it'll always stay on screen and not flash up and disappear whilst in operation? thanks again.

Comment: If you add `pause` at the very end, the `cmd` window will remain open (when the batch file is run by double-clock) and show all output of the code, which is mainly a `1 file(s) moved.` message for every moved file; to suppress these messages, append ` > nul` to the `move` command line; if you want to list every moved file, insert a line `echo "%%~nxF"` before the `move` command line...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with something like:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /s /b "REVIT FAMILES*.00*.rfa"') do move /-Y "%i" "U:\REVIT\Revit Backup Files\"
```